# В каком случае рекомендуется определять конструктор контроллера в Laravel и где и как создаётся и используется объект контроллера?

Tags: php, laravel

В документации о сервис контейнере Laravel мелькает конструктор в контроллере. Зачем он нужен? И где вообще создаётся и используется объект контроллера?

Comment: В контроллер инжектятся сервисы. Если они инжектятся не сеттерами, значит через параметры конструктора.

Comment: Что такое сеттеры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте для примера опишем техническое задание:

Представим, что мы разрабатываем роботизированую фабрику (завод) по созданию ручных блендеров.

Простейший блендер (пусть это будет наш *абстрактный* блендер) имеет ручку с кнопками, насадки (нож/венчик/прочее) и двигатель, который вращает насадки по нажатию кнопки.

Ну и пускай, наш завод будет делать 3 разных типа блендеров:

- бюджетный блендер с одной скоростью;
- более дорогой блендер c одной скоростью и чуть более мощным двигателем;
- блендер премиум класса, с 6ю скоростями, турбо режимом и значительно более мощным двигателем.

  ```
  final class BlenderType {
      public const BUDGET_BLENDER = 1;
      public const MEDIUM_BLENDER = 2;
      public const PREMIUM_BLENDER = 3;
  }
  ```

Итак, с тем, чем мы занимаемся мы разобрались. Давайте перейдем к реализации наших вещей:

```
interface IEngine {}
final class WeakEngine implements IEngine {}
final class MediumEngine implements IEngine {}
final class PowerfulEngine implements IEngine {}
```

По аналогии у нас будут классы насадок и ручек...

Нам предстоит *собирать* эти блендеры, как мы можем это делать? Ну, самым простым способом будет создавать комплектующие части блендера прямо в конструкторе (жесткая связанность):

```
/**
 * Бюджетный блендер
 */
class BudgetBlender {
    private $blenderHandle;
    private $nozzle;
    private $engine;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->engine = new WeakEngine();
        $this->blenderHandle = new PrimitiveBlenderHandle();
        ...
    }
}

/**
 * Блендер среднего класса
 */
class MediumBlender {
    private $blenderHandle;
    private $nozzle;
    private $engine;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->engine = new MediumEngine();
        $this->nozzle = new PrimitiveBlenderHandle();
        ...
    }
}

и т.д.
***
```

Какие очевидные минусы у этого подхода и что нас ожидает в будущем при каких либо изменениях?

Первый минус - нам необходимо создавать каждый раз новый класс блендера, если мы захотим создавать еще один тип блендеров.
Второй - если завтра мы решим, что бюджетные блендеры должны продаваться с двумя разными двигателями (от разных производителей например), то нам придется создать два разных класса, но по сути одинаковых - `BudgetBlender1` & `BudgetBlender2`.
То есть, одной из основных проблем такого подхода является линейный рост кодовой базы при расширении ассортимента или добавлении новых комплектующих.

А как насчет тестирования продуктов? Ведь с точки зрения бизнеса, будет глупым покупать каждый раз комплектующие (которые уже протестированы и работоспособны), чтобы протестировать работу нашего блендера. А с текущим подходом у нас не получится тестировать, чтобы было выгодно...

Как мы можем решить описанные проблемы?

Давайте рассмотрим два паттерна проектирования:

1. [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8);
2. [Service Locator](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/More/ServiceLocator/README.html), он соответствует [PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/) стандарту.

Оба паттерна предназначены для решения проблем с зависимостями в Вашем проекте c помощью [инверсии управления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (**I**o**C** - **I**nversion of **C**ontrol).

Первый паттерн предлагает *внедрять* извне комплектующие блендера (другими словами - *собирать* устройство из комплектующих, вместо того, чтобы создавать их в том же месте). Сделать это можно с помощью [мутаторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setter) (сеттеры):

```
class Blender {
    private $blenderHandle;
    private $nozzle;
    private $engine;

    public function setEngine(IEngine $engine): self {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        return $this;
    }

    ...

}
```

или с помощью конструктора:

```
class Blender {
    private $blenderHandle;
    private $nozzle;
    private $engine;

    public function __construct(IEngine $engine, INozzle $nozzle, IBlenderHandle $blenderHandle) {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        $this->nozzle = $nozzle;
        $this->blenderHandle = $blenderHandle;
    }

    ...

}
```

Второй паттерн предлагает создать *ящик с комплектующими*, где все аккуратно разложено и доставать комплектующие оттуда, вместо того, чтобы создавать их в том же месте.

```
final class ServiceLocator {
   private $serviceContainer = [];

   public static function get(string $key) {
       return $this->serviceContainer[$key];
   }

   public static function add(string $key, $service): void {
       $this->serviceContainer[$key] = $service;
   }
}

...

//bootstrap.php
ServiceLocator::add('budgetEngine', new BudgetEngine());
ServiceLocator::add('mediumEngine', new MediumEngine());
ServiceLocator::add('premiumEngine', new PremiumEngine());

...

class Blender {
    private $blenderHandle;
    private $nozzle;
    private $engine;

    public function __construct(int $blenderType) {
        switch($blenderType) {
            case BlenderType::BUDGET_BLENDER: 
                $this->engine = ServiceLocator::get('budgetEngine');
                ...
                break;
            case BlenderType::MEDIUM_BLENDER: 
                $this->engine = ServiceLocator::get('mediumEngine');
                ...
                break;
            case BlenderType::PREMIUM_BLENDER: 
                $this->engine = ServiceLocator::get('premiumEngine');
                ...
                break;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Оба подхода избавляют нас от проблем, которые присутствовали в предыдущем варианте, посколько теперь, мы легко сможем создать и протестировать наш блендер, создав объекты извне, *до* создания самого блендера. Теперь наш код не растет так значительно как раньше и мы легко можем тестировать его при помощи [mock-объектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82).

---

Здесь мы разобрались с двумя паттернами, давайте рассмотрим их реализацию в рамках Laravel-фреймворка.

[Service Container Laravel'a](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container) умеет две вещи - внедрять зависимости и выступать в роли собственно Service Container'a. Подробнее прочитать можно в документации.

Владея этой информацией, давай ответим на твои вопросы.

Для этого опять смоделируем ситуацию:

Представим, что мы пишем веб-систему онлайн-кинотеатра, в которой пользователь может скажем посмотреть информацию о фильме, перед тем как перейти непосредственно к просмотру. Информация о фильме лежит в базе данных, информации много и дергать каждый раз базу для этого накладно. Посколько информация о фильме не меняется ежесекундно, то нам необходим... кэш (да, я знаю, что у Laravel есть фасад [`Cache`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache)).

```
class FilmController extends Controller {
    private $cacheService;

    public function __construct(ICacheService $cacheService) {
       $this->cacheService = $cacheService;
    }

    public function showFilmInfo(string $filmIdentity): View {
        if($this->cacheService->exists($filmIndentity) {
            return $this->render('filmInfo', $this->cacheService->get($filmIndentity));
        }

        $filmInfo = FilmInfo::where(['indentity' => $filmIndentity])->get();
        $this->cacheService->set($filmIndentity, $filmInfo);

        return $this->render('filmInfo', $filmInfo);
    }
}

...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

     public function register() {
         $this->app->bind(
            ICacheService::class,
            RedisCacheService::class
         ); 
     }
}
```

Отвечая на вопрос:

> Зачем он нужен?

Для того, чтобы внедрить зависимость в Ваш контроллер. Я привел очень простой пример, Вы уже смотрите по ситуации. Это если вопрос звучит как "зачем нужен Service Locator", если Вы спрашиваете о том, зачем нужен контроллер, то почитайте вначале за [MVC паттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), по которому реализованы большинство современных фреймворков (включая Laravel).

Что касается:

> И где вообще создаётся и используется объект контроллера?

Как я уже говорил, Laravel реализован по паттерну MVC, в котором обязательно участвует контроллер. Создается он где-то по [call-stack'y](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2) в ядре фреймворка (см. `Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel` - interface & `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` - его реализацию) и используется там же для возврата ответа запроса.